# Union's default constructor is implicitly deleted

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following code:

```
struct non_trivially {
    non_trivially() {};
};

union U {
    bool dummy{false};
    non_trivially value;
};

int main() {
    U tmp;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1cMsqq9ee

Produces next compiler error on clang (13.0.0):

```
source>:11:7: error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'U'
    U tmp;
      ^ <source>:7:19: note: default constructor of 'U' is implicitly deleted because variant field 'value' has a non-trivial default constructor
    non_trivially value;
```

But successfully compiles using MSVC (19.30).

According to the cppreference it should be a valid code: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

> If a union contains a non-static data member with a non-trivial default constructor, the default constructor of the union is deleted by default unless a variant member of the union has a default member initializer .

In my example there is an alternative in U with a default member initializer so default constructor shouldn't be deleted, but it is. What am I missing?

Comment: The problem isn't with your default member initializer for `dummy`. The problem is with `value`. This for example, works just fine (and will function the same): https://ideone.com/GadqPM

Comment: @scohe001 I don't think that answers the question, if cppreference is to be believed.

Comment: When you get this worked out and compiling you'll still need to be very cautious. It's hard to get non-trivial `union`s working correctly. The usual advice is to use `std::variant`, but that's not all that useful if you're trying to learn the secret ways of `union`s.

Comment: Yes, `std::variant` is magic.

Comment: @user4581301 yep, of course, I met this behavior while trying to implement variant lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it was fixed in clang-17: https://godbolt.org/z/97rqexTxE

Answer (score 22):

This is [CWG2084](https://wg21.link/CWG2084). Clang and gcc are just wrong in deleting the default constructor if you provide a default member initializer.

The relevant quote that was added to the standard after the change was adopted (in [class.default.ctor]):

> A defaulted default constructor for class X is defined as deleted if:
>
> - X is a union that has a variant member with a non-trivial default constructor and no variant member of X has a default member initializer,
> - [...]
> - X is a union and all of its variant members are of const-qualified type (or array thereof),

(being the only two points that refer to union types, neither one applies, so it should not be implicitly deleted)

The workaround is to user-provide a constructor:

```cpp
union U {
    constexpr U() : dummy{false} {}
    bool dummy;
    non_trivially value;
};

// Or this also seems to work
union U {
    constexpr U() {}
    bool dummy{false};
    non_trivially value;
};
```

Comment: This is a **much** better answer than mine, WD.

Comment: Yep, I knew about workaround, but user-defined constructor isn't trivial :(
But thanks, you helped make sure this is a compiler bug.

Comment: @DenisVorkozhokov Unfortunately the compiler bug means you can't have a trivial constructor with a member of thiss type. Since you might be using placement new anyways, `alignas(non_trivially) char value_storage[sizeof(non_trivially)]; non_trivially& value() { return *std::launder(&reinterpret_cast<non_trivially&>(value_storage)); }` might be usable

Comment: placement new isn't constexpr, still not good enough :)

Answer (score 3):

It's all slightly mysterious.  [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/OMjqTCt8TDU08lHZ) behaves the same as clang.

The [standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#general-4) has this to say (emphasis mine):

> **Absent default member initializers**, if any non-static data member of a union has a non-trivial default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, move assignment operator, or destructor, the corresponding member function of the union must be user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted for the union.

But I think the wording is a bit wooly here.  I think what they actually mean is that you must provide an initialiser *for the member that has (in your example) a non-trivial constructor*, like so:

```
struct non_trivially {
    non_trivially() {};
};

union U {
    bool dummy;
    non_trivially value { };        // <-- note that I have added an initialiser
};

int main() {
    U tmp;
}
```

Then, [it compiles](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JKtkauRg35pNDSsG).

Comment: I suspect the note was originally placed after, or at least meant to be read in conjunction with the sentence later that “At most one variant member of a union may have a default member initializer.”

Comment: @Sneftel Perhaps.  It's still a bit vague though.

Comment: @Sneftel Vague enough to fool the clang and gcc folks anyway.